# Share a Post in native Android app directly through Graph API without any UI would block my FB app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I have made an Android application using Native Android platform. One of its feature is to Share post made by different Pages. I am sharing those post's data through my Android without any user interaction or any other type of dialog. I am using Facebook's graph API for that. Flow is simple, when a user clicks my button, post gets directly shared on FB. Everything works fine. **But will that behavior block my Facebook app in future ? Will that violate any policy of Facebook ?** Please suggest me an appropriate suggestion if that does violate. Hoping to get a quick reply to this question.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `POST /me/feed` API?

Comment: Yes, but I am doing that without Session. Hence no message from facebook like "Facebook would like to post your behalf". Direct posting. Makes sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are displaying a **Share** button explicitly, it doesn't matter that you are using Graph API (not the dialog to share). Its perfectly fine for the facebook, since people know what they are going to share.

But make sure the content is clean else if you get spams from your users. :)